# git & zend studio 8

Tags: eclipse, svn, git, github, zend-studio

hey, im using zend studio 8 and i just subscribed to github, how can i integrade them toghter? i installed mysysgit and also egit for eclipse but i dont understand what to do with both of them ...

Answer (score 2):

here you could find a easy setup git on ZS tutorial:
http://clintberry.com/2011/02/zend-studio-and-github/

Answer (score 0):

Have a loot at http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/ and http://www.eclipse.org/egit/ - Git plugins for eclipse.

"i dont understand what to do with both of them ... "

If you don't know from where to start, there are tutorials and forums found in Jgit and Egit pages.